# Rewrite rule to remove .php extension, redirects fine with R flag but returns "No input file specified." without redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

**Dev machine configuration:**

- Apache 2.4.16 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
- Server API   CGI/FastCGI
- Windows 8/10

**Goal**

My goal is to be able to make a request like:

```
http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path/a/b
```

and have it rewritten to:

```
http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b
```

**.htaccess file**

```
Options -MultiViews
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test_pathinfo

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+php* 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$ $1.php$2$3 [L]
```

**Test 1**

I make a request to: `http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c`

It works completely fine, including being able to access `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`information.

The rewrite log for this Test 1 request is:

```
[perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] add path info postfix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php -> C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c
[perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c -> path.php/a/b/c
[perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] applying pattern '^([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$' to uri 'path.php/a/b/c'
[perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] RewriteCond: input='/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c' pattern='!.+php*' => not-matched
[perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] pass through C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php
```

**Test 2**

I make a request to: `http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path/a/b/c`

This request returns the error: "No input file specified."

looking the rewrite log for this "Test 2" request...:

```
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] add path info postfix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path -> C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path/a/b/c
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path/a/b/c -> path/a/b/c
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] applying pattern '^([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$' to uri 'path/a/b/c'
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] RewriteCond: input='/test_pathinfo/path/a/b/c' pattern='!.+php*' => matched
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] RewriteCond: input='C:/htdocs/path.php' pattern='-f' => matched
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] rewrite 'path/a/b/c' -> 'path.php/a/b/c'
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] add per-dir prefix: path.php/a/b/c -> C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] trying to replace prefix C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/ with /test_pathinfo
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] strip matching prefix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c -> path.php/a/b/c
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] add subst prefix: path.php/a/b/c -> /test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c
[rid#e106e871a0/initial] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] internal redirect with /test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#e106e6bd48/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] add path info postfix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php -> C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c
[rid#e106e6bd48/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c -> path.php/a/b/c
[rid#e106e6bd48/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] applying pattern '^([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$' to uri 'path.php/a/b/c'
[rid#e106e6bd48/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] RewriteCond: input='/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c' pattern='!.+php*' => not-matched
[rid#e106e6bd48/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/] pass through C:/htdocs/test_pathinfo/path.php
```

**Test 3**

Now I make the same request as "Test 2": `http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path/a/b/c/d`

I just added a /d at the end of the request because I'm not sure if something gets cached, so just to make sure, I added a /d at the end, but the request is basically the same. But before making this request, I changed the .htaccess file and included a R flag, like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$ $1.php$2$3 [R,L]
```

Now, Apache correctly redirects to `http://localhost/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c/d` and shows the expected content from path.php

**My questions:**

1) Why does the redirect work and when I remove the R flag, it gives me a "No input file specified." error?

2) I read some other SO's answers and a few of them say that FastCGI is not able to access `PATH_INFO`, but in my "Test 1", `PATH_INFO` is accessible, for example, by printing `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. Did something change and now FastCGI has access to `PATH_INFO`?

Comment: "No input file specified." - this does not sound like an Apache error? Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file? Is there an .htaccess file in the parent directory? What version of Apache?

Comment: I don't have any .htaccess in the document root. Apache version is 2.4.16 and I pasted the whole .htaccess contents. I even removed some 3 lines of comments in the .htaccess, who knows, maybe some comments could be causing problems but no go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to include your `test_pathinfo` subdirectory when checking that the file exists:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test_pathinfo/$1.php -f
```

Otherwise this test is always going to fail, unless this file happens to exist in the document root. Alternatively, use the `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+php*

This regex is not quite correct and could cause some incorrect matches. `p*` matches either *nothing*, `p`, `pp`, `ppp`, etc. It looks like you've omitted the `.` and it should be `.*`. However, it should probably be rewritten as something like the following, or omitted entirely (since it is probably superfluous given the file check directive that follows).

```
# Request doesn't contain ".php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
```

> 1) Why does the redirect work and when I remove the R flag, it gives me a "No input file specified." error?

Well, that is a bit strange - it shouldn't work either way as far as I can tell.

> 2) ... FastCGI is not able to access PATH_INFO, but in my "Test 1", PATH_INFO is accessible, for example, by printing $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']. Did something change and now FastCGI has access to PATH_INFO?

As you have found, PATH_INFO can work OK with FastCGI.

It is the *handler* responsible for the request that controls whether additional path information is accepted. However, this can be overridden with the `AcceptPathInfo` directive (which you already have in your .htaccess file).

**UPDATE:** If this .htaccess file is in your document root then you also need to include the path to the file in your `RewriteRule` pattern, For example:

```
RewriteRule ^test_pathinfo/([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$ $1.php$2$3 [L]
```

In .htaccess the `RewriteRule` pattern is matched against the URL-path relative to that .htaccess file, regardless of the `RewriteBase` directive (which only affects relative path substitutions).

Comment: Thanks for the fixes to my .htaccess. Actually there is a path.php file in the document root! So maybe that's why it was not failing.

Comment: I had assumed your .htaccess file was in the `/test_pathinfo` directory, however, if this is in your document root then you will need to specify this path in your `RewriteRule` pattern (or possibly change the pattern to account for this). I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes, my .htaccess file is in the /test_pathinfo directory, not in the document root. My comment above was about having a path.php file in the document root and also a path.php file in the /test_pathinfo directory. That's why the condition `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f`was not failing even though it doesn't contain /test_pathinfo because it matched the path.php file in the document root. But the strangest thing persists and I can't figure out why using the R flag works and removing it gives me the "no file input specified" error.

Comment: Yes. But this still does not fix your problem. (?) I have tested these directives on my own server and it works OK.

Comment: No, just adding or removing the R flag and doing nothing else, changes the result. With the R flag it works but it shows the .php extension in the address bar. Remove the flag and the "no input file specified" problem shows up. Are you running Apache with FastCGI? Maybe you're running another server software.?

Comment: I have tried the above script on two Apache servers... one with Apache 2.4/handler and the other Apache2.2/FastCGI - they both "work". However, there are slight differences in the variables that are returned to PHP. Under FastCGI, the additional _path info_ is returned in the `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` variable (after the internal rewrite) as opposed to `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` when the request is direct, or when PHP is run as an apache 2handler.

Comment: I noticed that if you include the .php extension, such as http://www.penmarsh.co.uk/test_pathinfo/path.php/a/b/c then path info is returned in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. Also, including the .php extension, you get `[PHP_SELF] => /test_pathinfo/path.php/a/a/` while if you omit the .php extension, you get `[PHP_SELF] => /test_pathinfo/path.php`. Thank you for your help, maybe it's something with apache version, or it has something to do with the mod_fcgid that I downloaded from apachelounge.com